# SQLite Database connection creation globally or as the function runs?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, bots

I'm making a discord bot and performance is my first priority. I wanted to know that What If I make database connection as the function runs instead of globally? Which one would be better?
Like this;

```py
import sqlite3

conn= sqlite.connect("somedb.db")
```

Or;

```py
import sqlite3

def main():
    sqlite.connect("somedb.db")
    ...

# some other functions defined below.
```

Comment: How often is your function called? If very often you're better off creating the connection outside of the function. Pass the connection, or a cursor, to the function.

Comment: @mhawke Thanks for answering. My function is called really often. So, I'd make it globally thanks again for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance matters to that point, you should considere using a different language like C, or at least C++ or Java. While being an excellent language focusing on readability, Python was initially designed as a scripting language and performance is not its best point.

That being said, there should not be any noticeable performance variation between both ways: an expensive fonction is called once, full stop. The key difference will be the scope. Using first way, you have a module level variable, directly accessible from anywhere in that module. Using second way, you have a function local variable, that will have to be explicitely passed to all function called from`main`.

This is a *design* decision, not a performance driven one.